# Calculations in python with csv

Tags: python

How can I calculate the following using the csv data below
○ Monthly changes (expressed as a percentage)
○ The average revenue, and costs (and the corresponding months)
○ The months with the highest and lowest revenue

```
year,month,revenue,costs
2020,jan,5415,4206
2020,feb,1894,9843
2020,mar,1965,1802
2020,apr,1066,1709
2020,may,2002,2105
2020,jun,8338,3068
2020,jul,7749,2385
2020,aug,8834,2794
2020,sep,1303,1759
2020,oct,2004,1134
2020,nov,7624,1481
2020,dec,1882,3472
```

This is my code so far

```
import csv
def read_data():
    data=[]
    with open("revenue.csv", "r") as revenue_csv:
        spreadsheet = csv.DictReader(revenue_csv)
def run():
    data=read_data()

    revenue=[]
    for row in data:
        revenue=int(row['revenue'])
        revenue.append(revenue)
    print(revenue)
    print("Highest revenue:{}". format(total))
run()
```

Comment: What problem you faced is still not clear,it's more like a "Do it for me question" ... Till now you successfully read the csv file but then what problem you faced ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing calculations on a CSV you want to use the `pandas` module

First;

`pip install pandas`

Then read in your CSV:

```
import pandas as pd 

spreadsheet = pd.read_csv("revenue.csv")
```

You will then have a `Dataframe` which you can operate on

You can print the first 5 rows with:

```
print(spreadsheet.head())
```

If you want to work out the average revenue you could do:

```
avg_rev = spreadsheet['revenue'].mean()
```

The rest of the operations are on you, here is the `pandas` documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

And I recommend you read this:

https://medium.com/@kasiarachuta/basic-statistics-in-pandas-dataframe-594208074f85